# Testing factory behavior

Tags: java, unit-testing, factory-pattern

I am wondering what is the best practice to test factory behavior code.  In my case, the factory creates some dependency instances that will be passed to the constructor of the FooBar instance.

```
public class FooBarFactory {
  private Dependency1 dependency1;
  private Dependency2Factory factory;

  public FooBarFactory(Dependency1 dependency1, Dependency2Factory factory) {
    this.dependency1 = dependency1;
    this.factory = factory;
  }

  public FooBar create() {
    return new FooBar(dependency1, factory.create(), new Dependency3());
  }
}
```

The dependencies can be created by some other factories or can be created directly by the factory under test.

To test the factory behavior, what I have to do for now is create some protected getters in FooBar to retrieve the dependencies so I can assert the constructor injection and the dependencies were created correctly.

This is where I am unsure.  Adding some getters for the purpose of testing bothers me a little since this it breaks encapsulation.  I could also use reflection to retrieve the fields value but I usually consider this bad practice since it is easy to break.

Anyone can provide insights into this problem?

Comment: What confuses me is the sentence `To test the factory behavior, what I have to do for now is create some protected getters in FooBar`. You shouldn't have to use `FooBar` to test the factory behaviour.

Comment: How can I test that FooBar has been built correctly if I cannot use FooBar which is the result of the factory call?

Comment: You should test `FooBar` by injecting custom-made test dependencies and then in a separate test test that your factory produce what you expect. Don't mix the two tests.

Comment: I am not trying to mix the tests.  What I am trying to test is only that the factory has created a FooBar instance correctly.  For that, I have to test the building behavior of FooBarFactory, which produces an instance of FooBar.  Thus, the results of the factory are in the FooBar instance.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to mock the `FooBar` class and verify the constructor invocation through which the instance returned by `FooBarFactory#create()` was created. Using the JMockit mocking API, such a test would look like:

```
public class FooBarFactoryTest
{
    @Injectable Dependency1 dep1;
    @Injectable Dependency2 dep2;
    @Cascading @Injectable Dependency2Factory dep2Factory;
    @Mocked FooBar mockFooBar;
    @Tested factory;

    @Test
    public void createFooBarWithProperDependencies()
    {
        assertNotNull(factory.create());

        new Verifications() {{ new FooBar(dep1, dep2, (Dependency3) withNotNull()); }};
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As a Unit-Test you should test your unit (class) and just this.

The value created by a factory inside your factory should be tested on its unit-test. For example on your situation, it doesn't make sense to test what `dependency2Factory` return, because in order to `FooBar` work, `Dependency2Factory` should work too (in case it isn't configurable), if it is configurable you can provide your own mock and this would be enough.

And `Dependency2Factory` should be tested on a separated Unit-Test.

You don't test if the method `List.get(int index)` works every time you use a list in your implementation right?

Comment: I understand that I need to seperate testing concerns and in this case I do trust Dependency2Factory results.  What I want to test is that the instance returned by the factory is really injected into FooBar, which is the behavior of the factory (calling the factory and passing the instance to FooBar)

Comment: but in FooBarFactory are you able to configure Dependency2Factory?

Comment: so you could just inject a mock to create the object you expect and test executing something on FooBar (created object) that needs the bean created, if no NullPointer occurs and the mock factory was used it is working

Comment: I though about this too, but I was unsure if this starts to leek into functional testing since knowledge of FooBar will be needed to know how to trigger an NPE.

Comment: yes, this is true, but since the creation of `FooBar` depends on this, I don't see problem, you are testing if the object was right configured on `FooBar` instance. This is better than per reflection that you need to know exactly the field name... ;)

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the suggestion that comes to mind would be to in turn inject the FooBarFactory's dependencies as well, so that it takes a Dependency1 and Dependency2Factory as either constructor parameters or as values in setter methods.

Answer (score 0):

How about mocking? Mock every dependency required to run the tested piece of code.
There are a few good mock frameworks like mockito.